# Debugging the server side code after clicking on gmail

Tags: spring-mvc, user-interface, gmail

I am working on a project in which control goes from controller to gmail and goes back to controller ... i.e. User needs to confirm in the mail so that the method in controller is called. How to get the debug point working after clicking on that link

Comment: Same as on any other Server component. Attach your debugger to the server process and set a breakpoint in the endpoint which is called by the link in your email. Then when the link is clicked in gmail (or for instance you just enter the link in the browser address bar) and the route is correctly configured, the breakpoint will be hit.

Comment: But  due to security issues... we cant open gmail in our system. So I am clicking the link on mobile and  Please let me know how to make the debugger works after clicking the link on my mobile.

Comment: It's irrelevant where you click the link because the code you want to debug runs on your machine and not at gmail or your mobile device. So once you click the link, there is a request to your server. Of course, for this to work, your server has to be reachable from the outside

Comment: yeah.. how can I make my mobile reachable to my machine.

Comment: Well your server must have a public IP address, a domain name pointing to that IP and  rule in the firewall to allow traffic for the port you are using.

Comment: Can you let me know ... Is there any setup or commands that I need to use... to make it work?

Comment: As we don't know your environment this is impossible. Get some tutorials on basic networking.